# Is Dynamic Routing is possible between Azure IOT Edge Device Modules?

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-edge

When defining an Azure IOTEdge Device Deployment Manifest you must define routes for messages between Modules,

I am dynamically configuring the messages being sent from one module

[The documentation below states](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/module-composition?view=iotedge-2020-11):

> "There are no wildcard options in the sink property."

Since this is the case is there any way to dynamically generate routes at runtime as I would like different message types to be sent to different inputs?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to dynamically set routes.

You could use MQTT, which is currently in preview, on IoT Edge in combination with custom topics.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/how-to-publish-subscribe?view=iotedge-2020-11

Comment: thanks for the confirmation, that's what I feared